# Windows 64 bit Server vs x64 apps

Tags: dll, 64-bit, windows-server

I have the source code for a 32-bit dll (Windows) that I am trying to re-compile as a 64 bit dll.  I have been told that the app "can compile in VC++ 64-bit mode to target AMD64 or Itanium processors running Windows 64 bit Server."

I am trying to decipher this: if it runs on Windows 64 bit server, should it also run on x64 bit Windows?

Comment: [The] 32-bit dll (Windows) "can [be re-]compile in VC++ 64-bit mode to [..] target [..] Windows 64 bit Server." <-- Is what I read. A 64-bit processor is a *requirement* of running a 64-bit windows. If the process desiring to *load* the DLL is 64-bit then the DLL *must* be 64-bit. Otherwise, if the process is 32-bit then the DLL should be 32-bit.

Comment: So, theoretically at least, the code that now is used to create the 32bit dll should compile without any problems under x64?

Comment: According to the source quoted in the post :) YMMV. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AMD64 and x64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD64) and x86-64, and Intel64 and EM64T are essentially same thing, with different names.

Comment: +1 for the link. I didn't realize Intel "re-branded" it for their use (or that there are subtle differences)

Comment: IA64 and Itanium are the same thing too.  Involuntarily rebranded to Titanium.